# What is the browser support for the "digitalbazaar/forge" lib (native JavaScript TLS implementation)

Tags: javascript, ssl, encryption

I'm using the [digitalbazaar/forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) JS library, but I cannot find anywhere what the browser support is. Does anybody know?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not really designed for in-browser usage: you will lose the ability to verify the certificate properly, and might not have a suitable PRNG, for example.

Comment: Hmmm, I've seen that it does try to fall back to the new browser PNRG native methods, and if that is not there it takes some browser meta data to seed the Math.rnd. So they did look at it I guess

Comment: Nevertheless, from a UI point of view, you won't be able to know for sure that the cert is what it says it is. In a browser, everything that is designed to indicate whether the communication is secure or not is *outside* the scope of the page for a reason: you shouldn't be able to present a fake page with similar signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging we found that forge uses `window.JSON` and `Object.create` and other more ECMAScript 5 stuff. This means that out of-the-box the lib doesn't work in IE7 and below.

We included two shims: [ES5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) and [Json3](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3) and with those in place the code ran without any issues.

I'm not sure of the comments of @bruno (see above) are valid or not for our use case (we're not using TLS itself, but other encryption stuff that is also in the lib), but with respect from it just running this seems to work on all browsers we tested it in (IE6 and up, chrome, firefox, mobile safari, mobile android and opera mini).

What will be worse in the older browsers is the entropy of the PRNG's seed because they do not have a strong native entropy source, which makes the encryption a lot less secure in those browsers.